# CSS selector of 'compose' button in Gmail invalid when used as selector in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, css, puppeteer

Right now I am trying to write a script which sends email automatically. I am using Puppeteer. In the process of sending an email from gmail I have to click on the 'compose' button obviously. So right clicked on that button and clicked on the inspect option. Afterwards I copied the selector of this element (you can do this by right clicking the part of the code that appears and click copy>copy selector). The selector is `#\3a 4e > div > div`. Then I copied this in my script and tried to run it, but I got an error :

```
'#a 4e > div > div' is not a valid selector.
```

What seems weird to me is that the `\3` has disappeared.

I dont understand why it is not a valid selector. I have been using puppeteer using other websites and there I did the same procedure of copying the selector and using that in the script. Somehow in this case it doesn't work. I have to note that I am new to this business.

Comment: Did the selector you copied actually work in the first place? To me it seems like a bug where the backslash is misplaced, turning the `3` into an unknown character, instead of actually escaping the `#`. And the `\3` did not disappear. It is still there, but it's not being visually displayed as it's a character unknown to the console. As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0xevhp4/), the `\3` is still a part of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Since the selector itself contains a backslash, you need to escape it (with another backslash) if you include it in a JavaScript string literal:

```
var selector = '#\\3a 4e > div > div'
```